# How to split an edit text field into two separate fields when a particular radio button is selected

Tags: android

I am creating an app that contains an edit text field for measurement whose default unit is centimeter but I want it to split into two separate fields when a radio button is selected that is supposed to change the unit of measurement to feet, inches. ie two separate fields, one for feet and one for inches.
Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Literally I have no idea how to do it so nothing yet. I can make the designe but don't know how to make that designe work as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two `EditText` within `LinearLayout` and add weight in both the `EditText` setting the visibility of second EditText will do the split stuff for you.

Comment: But this will be visible all the time. What I actually want is suppose there are two radio buttons one says centimeters and the other says feet and inches. Now when the user click on "centimeters" then only one EditText should be visible and only that should take the input whereas is the user click on "feet/inches" button then there should be two EditText boxes visible side by side, one for feet and other for inches. Is it possible?

Comment: it wont be visible all the time, when u select centimeters..set the visibility of one EditText gone and when u select feet/inches set the visibility of that EditText visible

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!